# How to find which websites are the most cited in accepted answers?

Tags: discussion, statistics, data-explorer

Is there a way to find which websites are the most often linked to or cited  in good quality answers on  Stack Exchange?

The problem I'm trying to solve is: given a website which I know nothing about its quality, I would like to know how reliable it is. One measure that came to my mind is how often it is used in accepted and upvoted answers on Stack Exchange.

PS: besides the number of upvotes and downvotes for an answer, which other criterion could be used for estimate how good an answer is ? StackExchange is probably using internally the reputation of voters, but we don't have access to this info, right ?

Comment: You'd go and query the [data dump](http://data.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks I didn't know we had access to the data at such a level.

Comment: Define "good quality answers". I'd guess that w3schools is referenced in a lot of answers, and even upvoted a lot of times, but that doesn't make them good quality.

Comment: @Wooble: Those clowns are one of the reasons we get so many stupid questions in the first place! ;)

Comment: As I doubt we have access to who has voted for which answers, maybe a good answer is an an accepted answer with some upvotes ?

Comment: hm... list 10 most common websites you can link to. Try to come up with at least 10 and the magic will happen ;)

Comment: The most common "http://" included in accepted answers is definitely a link to another SO resource. jsfiddle.net definitely second,

Comment: You might be able to modify the queries here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99699/who-wants-to-go-spam-hunting to not group by users, but to instead search for common URLs among accepted and / or highly upvoted answers.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417190/441757 and https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1577350/which-sites-are-currently-linked-to-most-often-in-stack-overflow

Answer (score 8):

I have taken the simplest approach to give some sort of outcome that you can work with. I used [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/412902)

```sql
select substring(url,1, charindex('/', url, 9)) as site
     , count(*)
from (
select top 1000000
       id 
    -- , charindex('<a href="http',body) as start
    -- , charindex('"', body, charindex('<a href="http',body) + 16) as endi
     , substring(
         body, 
         charindex('<a href="http',body) + 9, 
         charindex('"', body, charindex('<a href="http',body) + 16) -
         (charindex('<a href="http',body) + 9) ) + '/' url
     , body
from posts
where 
-- which posts get selected
    posttypeid = 2 -- A
and score > 0
and body like '%<a href="http://%'
) as answers
group by substring(url,1, charindex('/', url, 9))
order by count(*) desc
```

Which produces after over a minute of processing time this result:

[image: sites with their counts]

Notice that the query only takes 1,000,000 answers into account. More will probably timeout on SEDE. The query only finds and includes the first link found. If the answer has multiple links you have to find other ways to get those. This query is more of a rough idea how you can narrow down your scope tp get the result that is usefull for your goal.