# Can we decrease the roomba times for auto deletion of bad questions?

Tags: feature-request, low-quality-posts, deleted-questions, moderation, automatic-deletion

In an attempt to improve the quality of content on the site, expediting the speedy deletion of low quality questions, while [taking pressure off the community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370993/with-a-userbase-as-diverse-as-stack-overflows-how-will-we-arrive-at-an-actiona/371015#371015). Can we decrease the roomba times for auto deletion of some  questions?

Currently [Roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) is as follows (emphasis added):

> If the question is more than 30 days old, and ...
>
> - has −1 or lower score
> - has no answers
> - is not locked
>
> ... or ...
>
> - it was closed and migrated to a different site
>
> ...or...
>
> - it was migrated from a different site, and then rejected
>
> ... it will
>   be automatically deleted. These are termed "dead" questions
>   (RemoveDeadQuestions, RemoveMigrationStubs in the case of a migration
>   or RemoveRejectedMigrations in the case of a rejected migration).
>
> If the question is more than 365 days old, and ...
>
> - has a score of 0 or less, or a score of 1 and a deleted owner
> - has no answers
> - is not locked
> - has view count <= the age of the question in days times 1.5
> - has 1 or 0 comments
> - isn't on a meta site
>
> ... it will be
>   automatically deleted. These are termed "abandoned" questions
>   (RemoveAbandonedQuestions).
>
> These checks are run every week across all sites.
>
> If the question was closed **more than 9 days ago**, and ...
>
> - **not closed as a duplicate**
> - **has a score of 0 or less**
> - is not locked
> - has **no answers with a score > 0**
> - **has no accepted answer**
> - **has no pending reopen votes**
> - **has not been edited in the past 9 days**
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted.

Focusing on the last condition. As a suggestion, can we append another condition?

> If the question **is closed/ on hold**, and ...
>
> - **not closed as a duplicate**
> - **has a score of -2 or less**
> - **is not locked**
> - **has no answers**
> - **has no pending reopen votes**
> - **has not been edited since closure**
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted.

Or something similar.

Even better would there be much overhead to run a script on Stack Overflow that would run once a day and do this clean up? It might help to alleviate some of the pressure and frustration for the community's curators and it would certainly make the site cleaner. The worse thing that can happen is the question is edited and flagged to be undeleted. This wouldn't require much effort to moderate, as a quick review of the post would determine it's viability.

**As noted** in the comments and my linked [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/371015/3956566), we need to reduce the number of close votes, but it's already been asked here [Reduce the number of votes required to close a question to 4](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348560/reduce-the-number-of-votes-required-to-close-a-question-to-4). This is an adjunct to that, and the improved UI on asking questions to assist with content clean up.

Comment: In what way would this _"take pressure off the community"_? The 'damage' will already have been done at this point. I for one usually don't care anymore once questions are closed (except when looking at the reopen queue).

Comment: What is this "roomba" that you speak of?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes, it needs to be easier to close them as well.

Comment: @PeterMortensen [roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173513/turbocharging-the-roomba-solutions-for-premature-deletion)

Comment: I'm not sure what benefit this would ultimately have. Having them hang around longer isn't an issue, but we do need to be able to close them quicker in the first place. I don't really care after that happens.

Comment: I'd rather change the criteria of roomba (duplicates don't go away even with zero score & zero score answers for instance) stuff like that

Comment: also you know that asking for changes in the site is most of the time a big "yeah, in 6 or 8 weeks".

Comment: @DavidG I've been pressing for [4 vote closure](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370993/with-a-userbase-as-diverse-as-stack-overflows-how-will-we-arrive-at-an-actiona/371015#371015), no point asking [again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348560/reduce-the-number-of-votes-required-to-close-a-question-to-4), but I'm lobbying the CM in private also. This is an adjunct to trying to make the closes easier

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre please write an answer with suggestions.

Comment: @pnuts will do that

Comment: I'm not sure whether this solves a problem we have - I may be wrong, but I doubt there are a lot of new visitors to an already-closed question with a negative score.

Comment: @YvetteColomb err I'll pass on that one. I stopped believing that we can change something in SO mechanics, everything get denied. and there are so many suggestions to do (already done, mostly), that I'd have the impression to repeat stuff.

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262077/what-should-the-system-be-deleting-automatically-that-it-already-isnt?rq=1

Comment: Yes, but you didn't answer my question and *this* post, what is the benefit of deleting quicker? This site has a long term goal and the roomba assists with that. Deleting quicker will only stop reopens (which are already hard to do) and frustrate new users even more. The "make it easier to close" ideal though, is a different thing completely.

Comment: What about those questions which get down-voted initially (due to poor explanation or whatever reason) but later OP improves it; finds a solution and adds the answer in the question itself like "*UPDATE:* solved! , _well it was due to this.....did this... and that....got it solved_"?

Comment: @Viney agree - we would have to test run it. They can be flagged to be undeleted. That actually happens with mod deleted posts. Hm could have an undelete  queue. Opens another can of worms.

Comment: @DavidG I'll have to get some stats on how many and how quickly such posts are edited to be reopened. Perhaps a roomba time frame of 3 days, or something to incorporate that threshold. It's about getting rid of the litter from the site.

Comment: But the litter is already being removed. I don't understand why you think it's going to be better if it gets removed quicker.

Comment: @DavidG because wading through the site at times is a little like walking through a tip. Littered with low qual posts. That's my opinion. If you don't think it's a problem, that's ok. I personally do not like it

Comment: The only time I see closed posts is when I go to answer them and they've been quickly closed or I've hung around trying to help a user despite them asking poor questions. Where/how are you using the site that causes all these closed questions to show up?

Comment: @DavidG https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest

Comment: So you want the list of newest questions to be tidied up? That's a noble goal but how does that marry up with the 3 days closing rule you suggested?

Comment: @DavidG this just feels like an argument tbh. You don't see the value in what I think is valuable. Whatever you're searching on, closed questions will show up.  We don't need to implement it, it's an idea. This search throws up dupes https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=null%20pointer%20exception&mixed=0. Either way, if people search on newest, it would be nice if it was clean

Comment: It doesn't feel like an argument to me, I'm trying to clarify why you think his is a good idea. I don't think it solves any of the problems you say it does and I'm fairly sure it actually causes more. Searching on newest posts will always show up closed questions, even if you roomba them after 2 hours. The only way to avoid that would be hide closed questions by default. But that's a different feature request, and maybe not a bad one as it new users wouldn't be aware of it.

Comment: @Viney I don't think "add the answer in the question itself" is an *improvement* in the question.

Comment: @user202729 Yeah but I am not worried about the question I am worried of the answer that would get deleted with it.

Comment: @Viney Tell OP to improve the question, get it reopened, and then post a proper answer. We *do* need good answers, but we also need reasonable questions for it to stay in. / If you think it's particularly important you can repost a Q&A yourself.

Comment: @YvetteColomb What particular problem are you trying to solve with this?  IIRC LQ closed question drop out of the main page and when you are looking through tag specific question lists it says closed/on hold in the title so it is pretty easy to see that you can skip it.  I just don't see a real problem with having these questions around for 9 days before they are deleted.  Dev time is precious and I'm just not seeing enough ROI on this to make it worth there investment.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm trying to solve one problem in two parts. Removing bad content off the site quickly as possible. Whether this is the right way to go about it, or tweaking it. One thing for sure is we need to be able to close things more quickly. Considering most posts are not reopened (due to remaining off topic) I think the sooner they're deleted the better, there's no worth having the rubbish floating around the site. IMO.

Comment: Sure, but once it's close it is pretty much guaranteed to be deleted.  Why not just change the 9 days to 5 or 7 and work on part one of the problem which is the the bigger part, just getting the stuff closed.

Comment: @NathanOliver that's exactly what I want to hear! Write up an answer. If this is too strict, maybe we can reduce the time, and still give them the window that most questions would be edited during.

Comment: Shameless self-promotion: I have a [loosely-related proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370629/closed-upvoted-questions-with-no-answers-should-roomba) to make closed, upvoted questions with no answers or activity for a certain period Roomba. Plus, of course, the proposal to reduce the number of close votes required to close a question (which I think would help with the close vote queue size).

Comment: @EJoshuaS shameless away, it's helpful to link them :D

Comment: In any case, I agree with making these questions Roomba faster, especially if it was closed within a few minutes of being posted. In that case, the OP has no excuse not to edit promptly. It's a little different if it was closed days or weeks after being posted - then it's less clear that the OP was just being unresponsive.

Comment: @EJoshuaS omg that makes a very good point! perhaps write and answer?

Comment: What harm are these questions doing for you?  Pretty sure no harm at all.  Leave them so they have a better chance of being updated.

Comment: @Brad unfortunately most of them are not reopened, so why leave them lying around for 9 days. Perhaps I've been too keen on immediate deletion, 2 days may have been better.

Comment: @YvetteColomb *Some* are reopened.  That's all that matters, right?  The problem with Stack Overflow is that we're all a bunch of pendantic software engineers so eager to have a perfect clean precise system that we (collectively) forget we're also all humans trying to solve problems.  I'd hope that as a moderator, you would realize that the impact of fixing one question for someone, or leaving that question open so it can be fixed, will have far outweigh some old bad questions that we can all vote to delete anyway, if we choose to.

Comment: @Brad being a moderator, I do everything in my power to help the site, hence I ask the community what they want and abide by the site's rules.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm just not seeing the ROI on this.  If the problem we are trying to solve is to keep the site clean then I think we should focus on step one of the cleanup process and get the low quality content closed.  We can't delete it until it is closed so we might as well do that before we start tweaking how the Roomba works.

Reducing the vote count needed, giving tag badge holders more powers, stopping the low quality content from hitting the site in the first place are all initiatives I think we should focus on first. This gets things closed and allows the OPs the opportunity to improve their question(s).

After that we could look at possibly reducing 9 days to 7 or 5, or adding a new category to get especially bad content removed faster.

Comment: "ROI" forcing me to google from the beginning ;)

Comment: Agree with you completely @Nathan, though I'm still not convinced there's any benefit to removing content any faster. I personally don't ever see questions that are older than a few hours unless I'm searching for answers to my own problems, and in that case, I'd never get directed to a closed question anyway.

Comment: @DavidG I'm not seeing any benefit either but if we all of the sudden drastically increase the number of closed questions maybe it would be prudent to remove the worst as soon as possible.  It's hard to say until we complete step one.

Comment: I entirely agree with the sentiment. But regarding this: `Reducing the vote count needed, giving tag badge holders more powers`. SO has over the years declined these requests. There's no indication there'll be a turnaround. New posts with these requests are closed as duplicates and left to rot; old requests aren't resurrected.

Answer (score 38):

> If the question is closed/ on hold, and ...
>
> not closed as a duplicate has a score of -2 or less is not locked has no answers and has no pending reopen votes has not been edited since closure ... it will be automatically deleted.

This seems to imply that a question with a score of -2 and no answers would be deleted immediately upon closure. (And, equivalently, a closed question with no answers would be deleted immediately if it reached a score of -2.)

This seems bad:

1. It would put some questions into a situation where they could be deleted before the OP ever got a chance to edit them into shape. The "no pending reopen votes and no edits since closure" conditions don't help, because there's no window for those reopen votes or edits to happen!
2. Worse: if a question is deleted immediately upon closure, it'll "disappear" for the OP. They may never see the closure reason at all, as the question will disappear from their profile as soon as it is deleted.

Comment: The OP will still see the question when it's deleted.

Comment: Can you suggest some better parameters or are you not keen at all for the change?

Comment: @YvetteColomb I don't believe this change is necessary. Questions meeting a more general form of these conditions are already deleted 9 days after closure; I don't see any pressing need to accelerate that process.

Comment: @YvetteColomb They'll be *able* to see it, if they know the site well enough to know that there is a specific page showing recently deleted questions and how to get there.  In other words, some fairly small percentage will.  They *can*, but many won't.

Comment: @Servy you'd be surprised the number of people who flag their deleted posts. One thing is, an auto comment, that would alert the user and bring them to the post.

Answer (score 11):

> If the question is closed/ on hold, and ...
>
> not closed as a duplicate has a score of -2 or less is not locked has no answers and has no pending reopen votes has not been edited since closure ... it will be automatically deleted.

This is bad. As soon as an unanswered question with a score < -2 gets put on hold, it instantly gets deleted. There's barely any time for the OP to improve their question! The current condition...

> If the question was closed more than 9 days ago, and ...
>
> not closed as a duplicate has a score of 0 or less is not locked has no answers with a score > 0 has no accepted answer has no pending reopen votes has not been edited in the past 9 days ... it will be automatically deleted.

...is good enough. 9 days is an adequate window to let the OP improve their question (if possible).

Comment: What would you think about 2  or 3 days?

Comment: @YvetteColomb Nah, I hate auto-deletion. [My last answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370677) was too ranty, so I'm trying to sound just a little bit pro-roomba to farm upvotes. But in reality, I'm all against roomba!

Comment: I love that :) thanks for your frankness.. I understand too ranty... I'm striving for too understandy

Comment: I don't like Roomba either, you have my sympathies. IMO it is a very strange tool for a site that wants to be a good reference, and it kind of killed any motivation I had for posting self-answered Q/A, reminds me of the "minimum notability" factor for Wikipedia. Just not fun to deal with.  "Too Localized" got removed because programmers' crystal balls weren't good enough at predicting the future, but for some reason the Roomba stayed.

Answer (score 6):

```
If the question is closed/ on hold, and …

not closed as a duplicate 
has a score of -2 or less
is not locked has no answers and
has no pending reopen votes 
has not been edited since closure 

... it will be automatically deleted.
```

The **score of -2 or less** part worries me.

1. The OP may not get a chance to edit their question before it's closed.
2. It may change people's behavior and increase downvoting simply to get a question deleted. That would change the purpose of downvoting.

Per [Help Center > Privileges > Vote Down](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down), "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect."

Getting a question deleted without giving the OP a chance to edit it is not what downvoting is for.

Comment: I'm not convinced it would increase downvoting (much) - insta-delete-worthy seems worse than downvote-worthy, so if you want a question to get deleted, you'd presumably also want to downvote it (regardless of whether that will delete it). If anything, it might make people downvote *less*, and upvote more, to prevent questions from getting deleted (and that I'd actually agree seems like a pretty significant problem).

Answer (score 3):

Understandably in my opinion there seems some doubt ([eg](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371071/can-we-decrease-the-roomba-times-for-auto-deletion-of-bad-questions#comment610039_371071)) about whether we have an issue that might be ameliorated by this suggestion. No doubt the site is full of junk (eg just discovered one Q with [**hundreds** of marked dupes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371024/how-to-get-all-questions-marked-duplicate-of-a-certain-question-through-sede#comment609962_371034), and [723,807 Closed Qs](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3A1)). However deleting Qs more quickly might make very little improvement hence efforts be better expended on other activity.

But data to assess the merit of this suggestion is lacking – and I suspect could be difficult to obtain. Nowadays broad SEDE queries often seem to fail to complete because of [the time limit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312994/1505120) and a comprehensive picture may need to take into account inaccessible, or relatively inaccessible, deleted Qs.

The relevant data may include indication of the effectiveness of deletion other than through Roomba and the view count development over time. For the former the VTD count over time would also seem relevant. And perhaps tracking at least the *quantity* (because their quality is judgemental) of edits during the deletion process [ref](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371071/can-we-decrease-the-roomba-times-for-auto-deletion-of-bad-questions#comment610073_371071)).

A minor mitigating consideration is that Qs asked more than say 4 years ago might be ignorable for analysis purposes, in view of changes in interpretation of on/off topic.

We do though have some data that seems pertinent. Moderator tools, Delete votes, Most Votes for 30d at present shows only one [1](https://stackoverflow.com/tools) Q with more than one VTD. [It](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711140/why-isnt-smalltalk-popular) is approaching 50,000 views (net +187) and is a Community wiki dating back to [April 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/711140/revisions).

Clearly no sign of a significant problem in the last 30 days once a couple of delete votes have been cast on a Q (since more than 3 votes is very rarely required for a relatively recent Q).

There is a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/645099/list-of-top-100-questions-having-delete-votes-which-are-not-yet-deleted-by-votes) that also focuses on Qs when one VTD short of deletion. Being SEDE it is not fully up-to-the-minute but lists a mere 26 Qs. It seems 2 of these have since been deleted, 2 are locked, 1 is a 'special case'. So net a mere 21, of which 5 will not accept delete votes anyway. These are the remaining 16: 150743, 14753048, 16180745, 18190714, 24749009, 25233411, 25832014, 28724672, 30170465, 32404517, 33287588, 33762842, 34020362, 36923762, 48335157, 48946454 and, knowing meta, I would not bet on their now having much life expectancy.

So once *near* to deletion there appears to me to be little to worry about.

What about the first VTD? I have no idea how many Qs are in that state but would be wary of any automation that reads too much into a single VTD (consider audits in review queues for example!). Mechanistic intervention can go wrong and it seems sensible to incorporate human judgement in the deletion process, and not rely on a single user. (Otherwise "Close" might as well be termed and treated as "Delete").

Pending relevant and reliable statistics, I say "leave well alone".

Comment: I suggest using less abbreviations, it makes it hard to read. At the very least introduce the abbreviation on first use, for the benefit of people not that familiar with them.

Comment: Just an idea: run a query to get the view counts of questions asked in the last day that this might delete, and then run a similar query a week later to get the updated view counts (and check that the questions are still closed, and how votes changed) - diff these against each other to give you a count of how many views this feature would've "saved", which is a rough estimate of how beneficial implementing this might be. One should probably also check how many questions got reopened during that time, to quantify the drawback of implementing this.

Comment: @pnuts Something like that. Edits alone might not mean much if the edit wasn't good enough to warrant reopening - some manual inspection of edits might be good, assuming edits are common enough for it to make a non-negligible difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think that some of this could depend on exactly *when* the question was closed. There are definitely cases where questions in smaller tags will be closed days after they were posted. In some cases (e.g. burnination, tag cleanup) questions will be closed months or even years after they were posted. In these cases, it's a little less clear that it's the OP's fault for not editing sooner (although you could argue that they should've formulated the question properly in the first place so that it wouldn't have been closed at all).

I have a lot less sympathy in cases where the question was closed shortly after it was created (e.g. within a few minutes). In those cases, the OP has no excuse not to edit promptly, so if they make no effort to improve the question within a reasonable time-frame it's their own fault. Given that [they should be sticking around to respond to comments anyway](http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive), there's no reason that they need the full 9 days to edit.

Comment: Perhaps add the changing scope of the site over the years, as that's beyond the OP's help

Answer (score -3):

Closed questions don't need to get deleted so quickly because I do not believe that the number of "closed/on hold" questions is a problem.

- People can ignore them quite easily.
- Leaving a question around for a while gives a novice a chance to discover the comments and edit the question into shape.

Comment: @pnuts Yes, I understood that.  I don't agree with the OP.

Comment: @pnuts To me it was pretty clear that the answer was referring to the deletion of closed questions, although I edited it to make that more explicit.

Comment: @pnuts Well, there's another answer on +26/-2 which says roughly the same thing, so it seems there were a lot of interpretations similar to yours, people were just pile-on voting or it's more an issue of the arguments made in each answer rather than the bottom line.

Comment: @pnuts I think it's because it was an answer that read like a comment, before the edit. I considered downvoting it for that reason and then decided against it, as it does no harm. It's an opinion like the others, but with no added value.

Comment: @pnuts agree, that's exactly why I didn't downvote it. I didn't downvote any others, upvoted two. Because I didn't downvote the other answers saying similar things, it would have been confusing in terms of - well how is this idea different to the others? I'm not sure if I'm explaining myself well

Comment: @pnuts ah, I understand