# What if I don't want to answer but still want to help?

Tags: discussion, comments

In question *[Using a void* to change a char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51358150/using-a-void-to-change-a-char)* I gave a working line of code to help solve the OP's issue (making it clearer than the previous comment).

I've read *[Why do some people answer in comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4217/why-do-some-people-answer-in-comments)*, and that seemed to be the consensus here, specially when:

- the question is average/below par/borderline for "no MCVE/why isn't that code working"
- not a duplicate, or not clearly a duplicate (this would be too far fetched)
- answering would mean to fix this issue, but also the potential issues of the OP in other parts of code (since there isn't any MCVE)

So why am I pinged by a high-rep user advising me "not to answer in comments"?

> [image]

Should I just vote to close and not even try to help the OP? Or waste my time providing an answer that will clutter the site and may not get an upvote or acceptance?

(to illustrate this, in the meanwhile I have tried to make an effort and make complete answers out of comments and that didn't turn out so well: [Close Program when Compiling with gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51442049/close-program-when-compiling-with-gcc))

Comment: Vote to close because of "unclear what you're asking". Downvote, too. ~next

Comment: voting to close: done. But why not trying to help the OP?

Comment: I sometimes leave a *can you try <awesome line of code>* to verify if my assumption about their context is right. That line might immediately fix their issue which I see more as a side-effect of my intention. Knowing it is fixed , I move on. I can't really fix the perception that others see that as answering in comments.

Comment: @rene please don't answer in comments. Write a real answer

Comment: Your last comment looks a little bit ironic.

Comment: I wouldn't take it seriously. Someone went overboard once and commented "Don't help these timewasters, people like you should be banned." It doesn't take long to realise on SO you can't please everyone. I'd just flag the comment as "Obsolete / no longer required" and move on, since I don't like long detours in comments.

Comment: Its difficult. It can be tempting to try and help out to move things forward and we all do it, but it can just as easily derail the situation further. Everything has a proper timing to it, it might be that offering help in a comment will simply turn the situation into a "getting tech support in comments" kind of deal, a lost cause. The proper order should be closure and after the closure happens and the OP has their attention turned from getting a solution ASAP to understanding what's up, that is the moment to start and help out.

Comment: @LutzHorn I think it may be sarcasm.

Comment: I don't agree with Clifford here. If you don't have the time or capacity to write a full answer, it's totally fine to leave a comment IMO. It's much better than leaving a half-baked answer and it's the principle I'm trying to follow as well. (Fun fact - I started to type this as an answer, but realized that it's better as a comment. Self-proving a point is the best example.)

Comment: @the4kman : If you don't have the time or capacity, and the question is barely ten minutes old, leave it - someone else will post a better and more complete answer.  Note I have added an answer rather than a comment to this - you might comment on that rather then commenting on what Jean says is my opinion!

Comment: I am not sure I "_admitted that this won't solve the issue completely_"; the posted code had multiple issues - of which only one was causing the behaviour in question.  As such it was a complete answer.

Comment: See how non productive all these rules are.  Seriously...this question wouldn't come up if we didn't have the mods sniping AWESOME comments every once in a while and putting in their "Comments moved to chat..." even when the comments clearly relate to the question.  It is all becoming a waste of time.

Comment: People answer in comments because thy're on their phone and creating an actual response in the Answers section is 'too hard'. (direct quote from a recent comment 'answer').

Comment: @Jeeped that's a partial answer, but didn't think of that. Looks like a valid answer to me

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - But I'm on my phone! Actually, no not really but if I submitted an answer below it would probably include something like *"while being too lazy to invest the effort to compose an actual response, they have the dying need to prove to everyone else how superior they are and how they knew the answer before anyone else"* and that might be considered rude so I'll abstain and let someone else follow up on my lead.

Comment: that wasn't my intention. The idea was to provide OP a beginning of solution, without fixing the code completely because there was too much work

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - Yes, I see that's true; I was addressing a wider scope and yes, I've actually seen 'I'm answering as a comment because I'm on my phone and answering below is too hard.'

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The better way to put that is that you offered the beginnings of a future answer (to be written by someone else), you were not providing it specifically to the OP so they can run away and never be seen again leaving behind a question in limbo.

Comment: @Gimby Thats also a valid point. Often someone else will take such a comment and extrapolate it into an answer, serving a valid purpose after all.

Comment: Reading the question that prompted this Meta post, it seems like a prime candidate for a [canonical](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426205/) of some sort. I don't follow the c tag, so I have no idea what it might be; but it seems clear that the underlying issue isn't really anything to do with `void*`, but with trying to reassign a passed-in (by value!) pointer to a local array (that won't outlive the function anyway), rather than copying - i.e., standard issue with understanding indirection.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Not sure here, I've certainly engaged in "have you tried $technique?" comments before to try and help OP narrow their question down. Often times, this also ends up solving the question.

It's true that you shouldn't write full answers in comments, but I think leaving pointers for OP to clarify (...or realise the futility of) their questions falls under the "suggest improvement or clarification" part of the comment mandate.

You mentioned the prime reason yourself: OP may have multiple problems with their code, and you're trying to narrow it down. If that happens to solve OP's problem along the way, oh well...

Comment: Many times, comments like these that end up solving the problem are responded to by the OP with something like "That worked, if you make that an answer I'll accept it."

Comment: @DavidStarkey In fact, we can see in the screenshot that it was indeed the case that the OP asked for it to be made an answer so he could accept it.

Answer (score 30):

Let's first establish that the question is on-topic. If it isn't then answering is, in comments or as a proper answer, a no-no. Those questions are best close voted and down voted (to push them off the front page). Those questions are expected to roomba but if a question doesn't attract enough close votes in time, two comments will already block the roomba for ever. Your helping comments made the site worse.

With an on-topic question it becomes a bit more diffuse. Leave comments to:

- verify/confirm your own assumptions
- verify/confirm assumptions of the OP
- rule out any obvious fixes the OP might have already tried
- verify/confirm if specific Q/A, blogs, documentation has been seen

Any of those type of comments might accidentally answer the question. If it does, it is up to you how to proceed. Either point out that self-answering is allowed and encouraged , step over your initial desire to not write an answer or rely on the other members to write a proper answer.

I don't see much need to @-reply other commentors or it must be for clarification / warning about their suggestions, maybe an encouraging pat on the back to write an answer if you like what you see.

In all cases, clean-up comments once they served their purpose.

Comment: As noted in my answer, down-voting can be very discouraging for new users - it feels like (and often is intended as) punishment.for Naivety and inexperience.  I'd suggest improve or encourage improvement first, close-vote if the improvement is not forthcoming, and never down-vote for that reason; it is clearly not within the guidelines for down-voting at https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: I think posting an off-topic question is an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post so that is clearly within the guidelines and as you have noticed that is the only case where I advocate down voting. On the other case I have no voting advice at all as that is not where the question is about, nor this answer should be about.

Comment: Sometimes; but it is also a matter of opinion, the justification for the specific question cited in this case being "off-topic" entirely eludes me.  Everything needed to answer the question is there.  If a question has answers you need to consider carefully perhaps before voting it down for insufficient information to answer - because others clearly differ, and may be spotting information you have missed.  The point about "_not meant as a substitute for communication and editing_" is important here perhaps.

Comment: I get in perhaps two down-votes a year - I just feels harsh, especially for new users finding their feet.  Also it is just too easy to down-vote rather then comment constructively - seems somewhat lazy, the target may never know why he has been targeted, and will never learn..

Comment: I get of plenty of down votes and I don't care. Also this MSO question isn't tagged [tag:specific-question] so I answer *what if I don't want to answer but still want to help* and in that broader context the special case for off-topic questions is warranted, at least in my opinion.

Comment: I take the point about not commenting on other users comments - that was pointed out as contrary to guidelines also.  In this case his answer had already been posted as an answer by another user - it was only a few minutes after the question was posted, the comment itself seemed unnecessary at that time - real answers were forthcoming.  I have in the past suggested commenters post an answer, only to be told that the do not wish to expose themselves to down-votes and criticism or that they cannot be bothered to post something more complete - these are weak arguments IMO.

Comment: I don't think anyone should be forced to write an answer if they have indicated they don't want to, whatever their argument. If comments on a question are no longer relevant due to their content being covered by an answer the comments can be flagged as no longer needed, maybe with a mod flag in case it isn't directly clear how the comment is covered in an answer.

Comment: @Clifford That's why we suggest to add a comment when downvoting. Having a myriad of downvotes with no explanation can be demoralizing, but if you take the time to point out _why_ they're being downvoted, the new user should be an adult enough to handle constructive criticism.

Comment: @krillgar : I'd advocate posting the comment, and _later_ down-voting if appropriate action was not taken to resolve the issue.  The danger otherwise is you comment and down-vote and never return; in the meantime your point may be taken and the cause of your down-vote removed, but not the down-vote itself.

Comment: @Clifford Or you never return to check and see if the downvote is still warranted. In most cases, I've been tagged in a responding comment that it has been addressed, or further clarification is made. I've removed my downvote when the question has been improved..

Comment: Why do comments stop the roomba?  Do you have a link to any post discussing **why** this is the case?

Comment: @zero298 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)  in the 365 days criteria *has 1 or 0 comments*

Comment: Yes, but WHY is "1 or 0 comments" the criteria?   Is there any evidence it is a good/bad/indifferent criteria?

Comment: @JohnHascall I guess [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) queried [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/) for an hour and with these criteria he didn't delete 80% of the questions which seemed good to him. The uber meta has some posts: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173513/turbocharging-the-roomba-solutions-for-premature-deletion

Comment: If I'm reading that right, it only only apply to questions with a score of exactly zero, otherwise the 9-day cleaner would have gotten it.  Correct?   Seems to me that "0 or 1 comments" isn't all that helpful a criteria.

Comment: @JohnHascall no, the 9 day roomba only acts on closed questions. The 30-days and 365-days on questions that are left unattended but are not closed. I've made questions with a score < 1 roomba when I either got rid of any low quality answers or flagged comments to be removed. You might like [the roomba forecaster](https://stackapps.com/questions/7239/roomba-forecaster-when-will-the-question-be-roombaed-if-it-wont-why)

Comment: ... *Comments* block the Roomba? Wat. Sounds like a feature request waiting to happen.

Comment: Comments only block the 365-day roomba, so if the question is downvoted, the 30-day roomba will delete it no matter how many comments there are.

Comment: @jpmc26 there certainly are attempts to change those roomba rules: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371071/can-we-decrease-the-roomba-times-for-auto-deletion-of-bad-questions

Answer (score 14):

While some questions don't contain a perfect MCVE, *some* contain enough evidence that the question asker has tried (to the best of their ability) to post everything they think is relevant, and would probably be receptive to putting more effort into that if prompted with more specific advice about what to include.

*Sometimes*, you just have to ask them to try something in order to confirm a hunch, and that ends up fixing their immediate concern. That doesn't necessarily mean you've answered the question, though, especially if what you suggested was a bit of a dirty hack to just find out what's going on.

So, *fish all ye will* in good faith to help someone as long as you have at least *some* confidence that you'll be interested in writing a more comprehensive answer. It doesn't *obligate* you to write a masterpiece, but it's a better use of everyone's time if you at least consider fully engaging with the question in your attempts to help suss out what might be at hand. After all, *something* got you curious enough to ask, right?

Remember, folks *probably won't* spend time writing an answer if they see that you've satisfied the OP's most urgent concerns in comments, so please do consider leaving some crumbs for the next passer-by. In this instance, one might expand on variable scope, safe string handling, why it's good to be explicit about type safety and other stuff - so there was a moment to teach there.

While not *stellar*, we don't need an included header and `main()` entry point with a mock unit test in order to see what's going on there, and I think it's quite onerous to demand it simply to follow form when it's not specifically needed. The code ended up going in there, numerous issues were easy to spot - it wasn't  *undeserving* of an answer.

But just use your best judgement. Sometimes we poke a bit to see if we can suss it out and see a can of worms which we immediately want to avoid - that's okay. As long as you're not specifically *dodging* something by using a comment, and you have a decent history of writing nice answers, you probably have nothing to worry about.

I'm not going to pretend that question was *stellar*, but it was answerable and offered a moment to teach so .. maybe we're holding the tea cups a little *too* primly in [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) these days :)

Comment: yes, c tag is very unforgiving since _forever_ (well, at least since 2016 when I registered). Very wise answer.

Comment: Note, that the result of such sussing should be incorporated into the question.

Answer (score 6):

When you click "add a comment" link underneath an answer, you are presented with this textbox:

[image: screencap with comment boiler plate text]

The help text is quite clear that answering directly in the comments is discouraged:

> Avoid answering questions in comments.

Comments cannot be downvoted, only upvoted, and so an answer that could otherwise be at +5/-10 would just appear as +5. An answer in the comment can not be properly vetted by the community. You cannot edit comments to improve them after 5 minutes.

Stack Overflow is intended to be a high quality resource of **questions and answers**.  The **quality** control is possible because of voting, edits, and deletion. Answers in comments are detrimental to the site because they bypass the usual quality controls that apply to answers.

> What if I don't want to answer but still want to help?

You can help by **getting the question into an answerable state**. This might be through edits, or clarifying comments. Or you can help by finding an appropriate duplicate, or linking in a closely related Q&A. If the question is just bad and can't be improved, you can help by downvoting it. This helps the OP to learn about what gets downvoted and what doesn't, and it helps the community so they know not to bother clicking on a question with a deep negative score.

Answering in a comment makes the dubious assumption that your answer is correct and should be exempt from the usual quality controls applying to answers. We all make mistakes, so this is never a safe assumption.

Comment: good points made, even if I find this answer a little too "by the book" for me. I asked the question because I really disliked that who-know-better-than-me people ping me to tell me "don't do that". Maybe next time they should try flagging see what happens.

Comment: @Jean flagging a comment based on its technical merits, or absence of community vetting therein (which is the reason evoked in this answer for telling someone they should not answer in comments) only leads to declined flag and wasted moderator time, I'd hazard you know that :) telling other SO users through comments how one sees sharing the community's space sounds like an ok thing to do.

Comment: it's different to _invite_ someone to answer (because the comment has answering potential) than to lambast someone because he's answering in comments. In our particular "argument" with wim (I upvoted the answer above, though), I must admit that I don't hold the commenter in my heart, and his comment/answer wasn't very good (also _wrong_). Instead of patronizing the guy with "don't answer in comments", I would have commented back to tell him: this is plain wrong (with technical arguments). A question of personal style, probably.

Comment: But asking a user to avoid answering questions in the comments is not to "lambast someone" or "patronizing the guy", unless the language/tone is obviously mean.

Answer (score 4):

**Comments regarding meta discussions should instead be meta posts regarding the behavior in general.**

Meta was created in order to move the type of discussion about answering, helping, etc. in comments away from the main site. Do not engage in meta commentary on the main site.

- If you see meta commentary on the main site, flag it as no longer needed.

> Should I just vote to close and not even try to help OP? Or waste my time answering an answer that will clutter the site and may not get an upvote or acceptance?

If the post is going to be closed and removed, then isn't commenting also wasting time? This really depends on how you want to spend your time, and it isn't really right for anyone here to tell you not to. That said, if the question remains open, and your answer does not get an upvote or accepted, that doesn't mean you shouldn't post an answer. If the comment was truly an answer, it should be in an answer, regardless of if it will get accepted or upvoted. If the comment was merely a partial suggestion of something that may or may not work, then a comment is probably the best place for it.

- Answering in comments is not really ideal, and it should be avoided.
- Using comments for suggestions or unverified approaches should be encouraged.

Comment: In context, what is the difference between an answer, a suggestion and an unverified approach?

Comment: @Makoto - What aspect of differentiation there was unclear? The terms are fairly well defined and used here on the site, as well as with their general definitions in the field.

Comment: Neither "suggestion" nor "unverified approach" are mutually exclusive of "answer"... or each other. It is entirely possible (and acceptable) for an answer to suggest an unverified approach.

Comment: To some degree @TinyGiant, sure there are overlapping possibilities. However, I thought it was pretty clear we are talking about single sentence responses here. Answers which are one liner "try using .indexOf('foo')" are best left to comments (or wiki posts).

Answer (score 2):

The important question is: **why** don't you want to answer?

If the question **should be closed, it's much more important not to answer**, than to avoid "answering" in the comments. **If you can fix the problem** with the question without input from the OP, then **do that** rather than expecting OP to do it. But otherwise, tailor what you write to the close reason you have in mind:

- Unclear (and you can't clarify it)? Sometimes, depending on how OP clarifies some ambiguity in the question, you might want to close it as a duplicate of different possible options. Or maybe in one case it's a duplicate and in the other case it's a valid question, etc. etc. So, say those things, and offer possible duplicate links if appropriate. (Of course, VTC as duplicate instead if you're reasonably sure.)
- Duplicate, but non-obviously? Feel free to write a short explanation of why the duplicate you propose addresses the problem. In particular, if there's a long code sample and your response is "oh, the problem is *here*, and it's a common duplicate" - **definitely do not write an answer to "find the bug"**. Duplicates are duplicates. A comment that points out the problem and then links the canonical is fine, *even though other places on the internet might think of that as an "answer"*.
- Needs more focus, because there are multiple problems? If they aren't all duplicates, feel free to identify what those problems are, *in the course of noting* that this makes the question unsuitable for Stack Overflow.

There are lots of other ways it could go, I'm sure, but hopefully you get the idea.

That said, **if the question should stay open, then definitely don't answer in the comments**.

- If it's **"too easy" - that isn't a reason not to answer -** but it *is* a reason to try to think about what the underlying problem is, extract its general form, and go [looking for a canonical duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426205/).
- If you only have a **partial solution** or an idea about a solution - **post it anyway**, and consider making it community wiki.

In the case being discussed here, the underlying question seems pretty straightforward to me - and OP's framing is a bit misleading. The problem isn't to do with the weirdness of `void*` at all; it's just the usual issue of implementing "pass by pointer" properly - in this case, the passed-in pointer is to a buffer that the calling code needs to write into, and the code tried to use a local buffer and then assign its pointer back to the parameter (which is wrong twice: the assignment isn't useful because the pointer was passed by value, and the local buffer will be out of scope). Answers - as well as the comment described here - proposed to copy the local buffer's contents into the one pointed at by the parameter. As far as I can tell, it should have equally worked to cast the pointer and `sscanf` directly into the pointed-at buffer. Both of those look to me like standard approaches to a very common, and very *general* problem, that ought to have a canonical.

---

There's one borderline case that requires judgment: when OP's code has multiple issues, but the question only seems to be asking about one. Answering about that one often leads OP to try to ask about the others (especially since resolving an error may allow the other problems to surface, when the code otherwise couldn't have executed). Depending on the circumstances, this could have many different resolutions:

- Close as a duplicate of the asked-about problem, and comment to highlight the other problems
- Close as multiple duplicates for the problems in the code, and comment to explain
- Fix the example to be a proper MRE first, then answer about it

But please, please don't write answers that answer multiple questions; and avoid addressing "incidental" issues in answers. And please, please don't let OP get away with receiving an answer about the "main" question and then editing to focus on a new one. **The goal is to answer the question that was asked, and to have a question that prompts the answers** that are posted, and have it be a single question with all the answers being about the same thing - so that the Q&A pair helps build a Q&A library. This is *not a discussion forum*, and as such, the goal *is not* to get OP's code to work.

Comment: Re *"the local buffer will be out of scope"*: That is a beginner mistake. There must be plenty of duplicates and canonical questions. Though, as usual, [notoriously difficult](https://html.duckduckgo.com/html/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+local%20buffer%20out%20of%20scope%20C) [to find](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=48AOOynnmqU&t=44s) (or Google-fu deficiency).

Comment: (A starting point could be *[Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)* (31 answers. 2011-06-22. 1200 upvotes. ***1120 [linked questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/6441218?sort=votes)*** (***!!!!***). But there must be some from 2008 and 2009.)

Comment: (2010: *[Returning a reference to a local or temporary variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744264/returning-a-reference-to-a-local-or-temporary-variable)*)

Answer (score -22):

The practice has the potential to shut-down the question - the OP walks away problem solved and has no incentive to improve the question to the point that it becomes part of the valuable community resource or Q&A that is Stack Overflow.

By getting in a comment-answer before anyone has had a chance to answer more conventionally and fully, you rather steal the wind from those that take the trouble.  I don't think the "I have something to contribute, but not enough to warrant an answer" approach is legitimate; if that is the case, leave it to others - especially if the question is only a few minutes old.

I think that if the question as unclear or incomplete, that should be commented on and clarification sought.  When a question is barely a few minutes old I'd suggest commenting first, and only if the OP has not improved the question in a timely fashion (and I'd normally allow 24 hours to allow for timezone differences), might you vote to close.  A salvageable question seldom recovers from a closure, even when adequately improved, and it can be very discouraging for new users to have their questions knocked down before they get a chance to find their feet.  I'd certainly refrain from downvoting in most cases.  Naivety and inexperience should not be "punishable" offences.

Comment: *By getting in a comment-answer before anyone has had a chance to answer more conventionally and fully, you rather steal the wind from those that take the trouble.* - I wouldn't consider that an issue, just add the answer anyway. In the log run the more fleshed-out answers tend to get more upvotes by future visitors even if they aren't always considered the "accepted" answer by OP.

Comment: @MichaelDodd : You make a fair point, but equally the presence of an "oh, that is what I was going to say" comment may discourage the posting of it as an answer by someone else who may worry that it is plagiarism.  Jean has made far more of this than I intended though - he really shouldn't worry about one terse comment from me; and has been pointed out in the original question - my comment itself was also contrary to guidelines.

Comment: I regularly use comments to narrow the scope and give a quick line of code that could be an answer, usually when closing the question as a dupe or as an incomplete debugging issue. Sometimes because I don’t think I have a complete answer or time to write a proper answer. I can’t see why that'd be taking the wind out of someone’s sails. Please don’t tell people to “not answer in comments”; you could instead be more encouraging and invite them to post a full answer if you think it worth an answer.

Comment: And no, comments are not nearly rich enough to convey proper answers and people should not fear accusations of plagiarism if an idea or code snippet has been shared in a comment. A good, helpful answer is clearly going to require more work than just copying a line of code, and more power to those that put in that work.

Comment: We *discourage* full answers in comments because they can’t be voted on (up and down) to indicate their usefulness to future visitors, but there is no hard rule that states you can’t do so *ever*. If a comment helps someone, then that’s a small win.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : That is not how I interpret the guidelines at https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment.

Comment: Wow - I'm taking some punishment here  - for adhering to guidelines rather then opinion.  Oh well.  I'll stand my ground I think.  Note the answer has been heavily edited to be more general and less personal - that was previously inappropriate.

Comment: I agree with most of what you say, but your continued references to punishment are just a deal breaker. Downvoting != punishment.

Comment: Downvoting in meta, even less so.

Comment: "When a question is barely a few minutes old I'd suggest commenting first, and only if the OP has not improved the question in a timely fashion, might you vote to close" - I can understand that for a hours-old question in a low traffic tag, or an extremely hard question. But for a random python question fresh off the front page, defining "timely fashion" as 24 hours is simply unworkable - by this time it either has 10 answers or is closed/deleted. In high traffic tags, closevoting first and then writing the comment seems better, especially as OP can still react while the question is closed.

Comment: FWIW, it *is* confusing that the same rules supposedly apply across the network, but enforcement is so vastly different. Moderators on some of the other sites on the SE network do enforce no-answers-in-comments as a hard rule.

Comment: `By getting in a comment-answer before anyone has had a chance to answer more conventionally and fully, you rather steal the wind from those that take the trouble.` This, combined with the fact that comments cannot be downvoted upon (to avoid OP from assuming them as the *right* answer and then coming back after a day with a follow-up question) are compelling enough reason to discourage answering in comments.

Comment: @Clifford I'm guessing it is because the help page says "Comments are **not recommended** for any of the following". Emphasis mine.

Comment: IN the case of 'NULL terminator missing', 'not enough space allcoated for termiantor', 'correctly and completely handle the results returned from system calls like recv()', I don't want anyone to answer.  Any 'real' answer would be a pan-galactic dupe and not worth it.  If I can help the OP and, at the same time, get a bad question removed, why not?  I certainly don't want rep for such questions.

Comment: @MartinJames : indeed the first two issues you mention were problems with the code in question, but they were not the cause of the problem the OP was asking about - they were secondary, and could have legitimately been addressed in a comment.  Jean addressed the _primary_ issue in this case.

Comment: @Gimby : Agreed, I was being somewhat rhetorical.  However while down-voting is not provided for the purposes of punishment; it is clearly often used as such, or at least  may feel like that to the target who may have no clue what they have done wrong.  I'd rather not discourage new users of SO (and it is discouraging); they may one day have something genuinely valuable to contribute.

Comment: @Clifford: “not recommended” is not the same as “you must not do this”. Not recommended means that if you see this happen, it’s best to gently steer the other user to a better action or flag as no longer needed or to leave it be. Please don’t interpret “not recommended” as “I need to tell the other person not to do that”, because there is no reason to.

Comment: If the problem with "half answers" in comments is that comments cannot be downvoted, then the problem may be that you cannot downvote comments, not that people write things in comments, which do not deserve a full post (because they are still incomplete or similar reasons against an answer).

Comment: @MartijnPieters : I don't think we are in much disagreement, but the question here is about what to do with questions you think not worthy on an answer but on which you want to offer help, not whether or not I should have commented on the comment.  I have already conceded that was probably unnecessary, and will not defend that action.

Comment: Downvotes are not punishment. they are a message to others that it is likely not worth their time viewing the question. close votes are not punishment. they are a message to the asker that their question is not fit for the site and gives guidance on how to fix it if possible. if everyone refrained from using the built in tools to curate the site because they didnt want to be "mean" and "punish" people, the entire site would be full of bad, off topic, and/or otherwise useless questions and no one would want to use this site.

Comment: @Dragonrage :You are simply telling me what down-voting is for; I understand that - that is not what I am saying.  I am simply expressing an opinion based on observation of behaviour - take it or leave it.  I remain astonished that the consensus seems far harsher than the my interpretation of the guidelines.  I see no reason to _both_ close-vote and down-vote - one removes bad questions, the other affects the personal reputation of other users; users finding their feet on SO don't deserve that personal hit - it is unhelpful.  If they have rep and should know better - sure fair game.

Comment: @Clifford not everyone can see close votes. downvotes are helpful because they are more visible. i dont downvote to make people lose reputation. i downvote because the question/answer was bad. the fact that they gain/lose reputation shouldnt even play a factor in whether you vote or not; only the quality of the question/answer should matter.

Comment: @Dragonrage I am not sure that we disagree - at least not on what down-votes are for.  Just the aggressiveness with which they might be used.  THere are three option, up, down and nothing - so seem to consider that if it is not god, it must be bad.  If it is improvable, I'd prefer to encourage improvement rather than (or at lest before) down vote, and that is clearly what the guidelines encourage, and letting a poor question stand to give time for improvement is not unreasonable and does little harm.

Comment: I do not take your point about the visibility of close votes - it does not matter - the worse a question is the faster it will be closed.  Who needs to see that process?  That is two punitive actions for one offence - which is hardly fair.

Answer (score -22):

Lest we let this get away from us...

## "Helping" on Stack Overflow implies "answering".

That is, if you want to help someone with a question, you are by default *answering* their question.  After all, answers are the *only* thing on the site which provide value; comments are temporal in nature and can be deleted for any reason.

If you don't want to *help* someone, you don't want to *answer*.  If you don't want to *answer*, then there's no mandate suggesting that you need to do anything *else* to the question (e.g. vote, close, etc).

You're free to not engage with any question you wish.  But if you do want to engage in a question, don't be hesitant to commit to **answering**.  At the end of the day, only answers actually help the OP and others, as well as allow the system to function properly and expose *good* answers.

Comment: I disagree that answers are the only way to help.  They might be the only way to solve the posted issue, but the user can be helped a number of ways, like helping a new user understand how SE works or helping any user better clarify the problem they are having.

Comment: Maybe we need a clearer definition on what "helping" is. For instance, do we consider a comment such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51366210/an-easy-to-use-parser-for-external-dsls-in-rust#comment89704719_51366210) helpful? I would naturally assume that it is, even though there is certainly no intent of answering. Sending a user to another site in the network for their pure maths or machine learning question may also be considered helpful for everyone. For "helping" to imply "answering", you're also assuming that we cannot be helpful towards unanswerable questions.

Comment: So what you're saying is, if I don't know how to answer a particular question then I have no business in giving any feedback? If a question is well-structured and I don't know how to answer it, shouldn't I upvote that answer to make it more visible towards others who may know? If a question is poorly structured, shouldn't I downvote it as a way of expressing that it is unsuitable for Stack Overflow in its current form? If a question is lacking in particular details, shouldn't I comment to try and obtain those details from OP?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that there are plenty of ways I can help the OP and other users of Stack Overflow without necessarily committing to answer a question.

Comment: @DavidStarkey:  Help documentation and Meta exist to help a user understand how SE works.  Comments exist to allow a bystander or prospective answerer to ask **clarifying questions** of the OP to determine if their question is answerable (above all), if it makes sense, and what the actual problem is.  Conflating these two services is dangerous, and gives comments the puffed-up position that they enjoy today.

Comment: @E_net4:  I have absolutely no faith in any comment that says (in brief), "Your question is on topic over here."  The reason for that is that there is [**more** than](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73382/175248) [enough case study](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777/9874) to prove that users have a very, very low success rate when determining which site content belongs on.  So yes, I would consider that comment unhelpful given that such a comment may trap an OP between communities in which their question may or may not fit.

Comment: @E_net4:  Also, we don't migrate crap as a policy.  I'm ***thoroughly*** unconvinced that the question you linked to is even any *good*.

Comment: @MichaelDodd:  If you don't know how to answer the question, then don't answer the question.  If the question is unclear, ask a clarifying comment of it.  If you believe it to be a good question, then upvote it.  If you believe it to be bad, then downvote it.  If you believe it to be off-topic, then flag/vote to close it.  **None of those actions are mandatory**, which was my point.  You could choose to ignore it if you felt so inclined.

Comment: @Makoto By no means did I suggest that the linked question was salvageable, but it _still_ is useful: it directs the user to a place where they can receive assistance in what they were originally working for without cluttering SO with more bad questions.

Comment: @E_net4:  No, you're just moving the dust pile from one corner of the house to another.  If the question isn't salvageable, it should be laid to rest right where it lies.

Comment: @Makoto A request for an off-site resource can become acceptable outside the SE network. It's no longer a pile of dust in that sense.

Comment: @E_net4:  ...No.  That's wrong.  If the question isn't suitable here, then we shouldn't be inclined to feel like we could treat it differently than any other off-topic or unsuitable question and link to a place where they *might* get help.  Unless you're sure, **don't bother.**  You're only going to cause more harm to an OP looking for actual guidance by jerking them around like that.

Comment: @Makoto Right, got you. With the way you were phrasing it, it sounded like the complete opposite of that intention.

Comment: @Makoto the [aforementioned comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51366210/an-easy-to-use-parser-for-external-dsls-in-rust#comment89704719_51366210) says that the question is off topic and points the OP at **non-Stack Exchange** sites / forums / chatrooms where the question will be welcomed. Do I understand your point correctly — pointing someone to a better location to ask recommendation questions is actively unhelpful?

Comment: @Shepmaster:  Right, so...let's consider that this question gets deleted, either by the OP or by the system.  How useful is the comment, now that it's permanently lost?  (Note that neither the OP nor the system could delete a question with a positively scored answer.)  Further, how does a comment like this further Stack Overflow's goal of being a library of detailed answers to questions about programming?

Comment: *How useful is the comment* — it's a chance to make one person feel less alienated about Stack Overflow (plus bonus points for others who incidentally read it). Perhaps they will contribute more (on topic) in the future as opposed to being angry at a bunch of faceless Internet users and never coming back to SO. It allows us over in [tag:rust] to provide a better experience than [tag:c] or [tag:java] or [tag:c++] or whatever, which reflects on our community and our values on the world outside SO.

Comment: I do agree that the comment in question doesn't help make this question a better part of a repository of answers, but I *think that's OK* because the question should be deleted. That problem is going to take care of itself; this comment just helps OP learn from their mistakes and solve their problem in the meantime. This circles back to the original point: can we help if we don't want to (should not) answer? Your point, which I see now you mean in very black-and-white terms, is that if you cannot (should not) answer, you should not comment. I disagree, but that's neither here nor there.

Comment: @Makoto If we expect that new users have read help documentation and meta posts, then we are kidding ourselves.

Comment: This answer and all its comments, made me remember the time that I learned programming. I searched on the internet for my questions, and came to Stack Overflow. The website was very useful, and one day I made an account. I read the documentation, and gave my best try. Today, I'd say I didn't succeed. Some people saw only my problems, and not my potential, and I can say that I felt sad with some users' actions. I'm glad others cared, else I wouldn't have stayed here. Now, I want to be a useful resource, and help others. Please keep that in mind. Don't be rude to new people because they're new.

Comment: @Andreas: You'll have to show me where I'm explicitly choosing to be rude, especially to new people. Nothing I describe here is done with any tone or context into an OP's expertise or experience.  Ironically I feel like this kind of opinion of taking the mission and scope of Stack Overflow seriously is going to inexplicably get me into hot water with the new CoC.

Comment: @Makoto It's important to keep in mind that on the internet, what seems harmless face-to-face, can be perceived in another fashion. When being new to this community, and writing questions/answers on-topic, down-votes can feel rude. Being directly negative in feedback can also be perceived rude. You may have no intention to be so, but how can the person know that? By commenting in a helpful fashion, yet not answering, you prove that you're not rude. Note that what I said, was a general advice. I didn't say you were rude, or intended to. This conversation gave me a flashback. Hope that clarifies

Comment: @Makoto Sorry for being unclear

Comment: @Andreas:  I'm not being negative at all in any feedback, nor am I implying that.  You seem to be twisting my stance into something it isn't.

Comment: @DavidStarkey:  Your point is well taken, but you have to understand that documentation like that scales with the number of users that access the site.  Commentating on what a user should and shouldn't be doing or how they can actually have a good time here in a onesy-twosey way *doesn't* scale, and the sooner we accept that as gospel, the better off we'll be.

Comment: @Makoto I'm not suggesting the documentation is not useful.  However, it takes an experienced user to point new users in the right direction, like pointing out the FAQ.  Even seasoned users occasionally need guidance, like a link to the most recent meta discussion on a topic.  Outside of documentation, some of the comment-answers could also be seen as requests to edit the OP to include what's been tried.  It's just, saying "Have you tried X" sounds friendlier (and more helpful) than "Edit in what you've tried".

Comment: @DavidStarkey "please add <x> and <y> to your question" is a little friendlier though. Barking commands at people is not the best of ideas, brevity can make it look like that is happening. Musing about it, I think that's a little side effect of comments having a maximum length; you automatically start to become sparing with the amount of words you use to express something and that can sometimes lead to trims that end up not reading so nice.

Answer (score -26):

To specifically address:

> What if I don't want to answer but still want to help?

Providing an answer or even a hint in a comment may help the OP but does little to enhance the community resource of questions and answers.  So I suggest do nothing.

Comment: but answering a question that only interests the OP doesn't enhance the community resource either.

Comment: "This should be a comment" hehe

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre : I am not sure I am able to determine what ultimately turns out to be useful and what does not.  The question was answerable IMO - answer it; if the question is closed so be it; if any one objects to your posting in good faith and it attracts down-votes you are able to delete the answer if you wish.

Comment: @Clifford I am sure most people looking for an answer will read comments too if the question is not answered. That way isn't it helping the community ?

Comment: @AmitDwivedi : Not really; comments are regarded as temporary and I am pretty sure are not indexed for search either within SO or external search engines.  I have certainly never found a search hit for a comment, and the only way anyone is normally going to find an existing answer or question on a specific subject is by searching.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: "*but answering a question that only interests the OP doesn't enhance the community resource either.*" If the question is on-topic for SO, then answering it enhances the community resource. Indeed, that's how we *define* "on-topic". Your problem seems more that you disagree with what we consider "on-topic", which is an entirely different matter. But even if you disagree, posting answers as comments doesn't help the site accomplish what it's trying to.