# Low quality link-only answers

Tags: support, answers, link-only-answers

What puzzled me in SO practice: if I know some module or tool that can help, but I did not use them myself and cannot provide a code without diving into the API docs — should I remain silent about it to not get downvoting and reprimands? Or should I just mention them in a comment? But comments can be missed and other users that will read the thread can skip some helpful information.

Comment: This came up on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55029732/1251007

Comment: Could you not add usage details to the answer?  Answers that go, "Hey, try this thing over here" are of limited usage; it leaves it to the reader to check it out, read the docs, and then figure out that it might not work for what they need.  *Much* more useful would be, "Hey, this package here can do that, here's how".

Comment: I would say that in my opinion a comment would be the better option with an answer like the linked one. In order to be a _useful_ answer it should contain an example of how to use it.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371115/what-if-i-dont-want-to-answer-but-still-want-to-help

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You're free to choose how much you want to invest in your own contributions.

If you want to post a quality answer that meets the site's (and users') standards for a good answer, it's great for you to post one.

If you aren't willing to take the time to write a high quality answer, but want to provide some small bit of useful information that wouldn't be a quality and complete answer as it is, you're welcome to post it as a comment, in the hopes that someone else fleshes it out into a full answer.  (Note in the case that this involves referencing some product, as you described, be sure this doesn't run afoul of spam rules.)

If you don't want post anything at all, that's fine too.

Obviously we'd *rather* you take the time to provide the high quality answer, but it's not like you're *obligated* to.

And if you post something that is not a high quality answer, or not an answer at all, as an answer, you'll get feedback accordingly.  So don't do that.

Comment: Thank you. I just doubted that it is good for the site and people searching the info. Now if I have time limits and cannot take an hour to learn API docs while knowing that the module author is one of the most competent experts in the area, I still have only a comment option. But I've seen many questions with answers in comments that did not become real answers — and this was also not very helpful. But I understand that rules have many use cases and I will conform.

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt Knowing that the module author is extremely competent in the area does not prove that the module will be the answer to every question in that area; the module may not have been designed to provide the particular functionality the question asks for. If you have reason to believe that the module does provide the required functionality, it would be a good idea to explain that reason in your comment.

Answer (score 33):

So... The tricky bit here is: if you haven't used it, *how do you know it works?*

Not saying it doesn't, but I haven't used it either. So really, both of us are just guessing, hoping that the documentation is correct and that we're reading it correctly. Except, I didn't even read it, so I'm also just guessing that *you* read it correctly.

And that's the *best* case here. Common less-good-cases include...

- ...someone just googles every question and posts the first link, hoping to get lucky.
- ...someone promoting their PDF library, without particularly caring whether it solves the problem in the question at all.

So to recap: best-case this is a well-meaning but extremely weak answer. Common-case, it's either noise or actively harmful. And both of those are still true if posted as a comment...

As hard as it can be, sometimes the best option *is* to say nothing at all, deferring to folks who have something useful to say.

Comment: Well, I can trust the module author if I know them as an expert in the area.

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt then, post it as a comment: it's unlikely that it will be missed, unless there are too many comments already, but in that case it could hint that it may be a poor question to begin with.