# What is a beginner-oriented canonical Q&A and how can it help me curate my watched tags?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, closed-questions, canonical

This is intended to be a light satire to assist would-be site curators who find that the tags they're most interested in are flooded with low-quality questions, but who either misuse [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173) as a [canonical](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291992) Q&A to close questions; or fail to close questions about common problems as duplicates; or fail to identify or create canonicals with which to do so. (The question and answer therefore deliberately mimic or even copy phrasing from that Q&A; it's not feasible to cite all these references, so let me just take a moment here to credit Raedwald and SlugFiller generally.)

This question covers three classes of more specific complaint:

- New programmers and/or new Stack Overflow users (in many cases, both apply; but it doesn't really matter) do not properly attempt to debug their code before posting a question.
- The same people dump attempts at homework assignments, contest questions, puzzles from other tutorial/learn-to-code sites, etc. and vaguely seek help.
- When I try to close questions as a duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173), many people complain: OP, random passersby on the question, and regulars on Meta.

Comment: Well, there's stuff like the [What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/10871073) post.

Comment: True. That would be a lot harder to satirize, though. ;) But yes, many languages support regex; the reference question is a good place to look for a more specific canonical, but not ordinarily an appropriate closure target in itself.

Comment: And [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53645882/10871073) is, by its very nature, somewhat condescending as a dupe target.

Comment: I removed the callout, partly because of what you're saying here, and partly because the "how to use a debugger" question is itself actually tagged as language-agnostic.

Comment: And I know I've seen several other, similar, "101" so-called canonicals in other tags.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Satirize or parody? Those are not synonyms, you know.

Comment: @user3840170 I am deliberately employing the irony of mimicking the *tone* (as well as the form) of the original "what is a debugger" question in addressing subject-matter experts, in criticizing their question-closing conduct. The goal is to inspire a bit of humility. I think this qualifies as satirical. I am not *merely* mimicking the form because it's funny to do so.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A [canonical Q&A is](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291992), as BradleyDotNET puts it, "a broad question/answer pair that is intended to be a duplicate target for commonly asked questions", designed to avoid having duplication of Q&A. A *beginner-oriented* canonical covers an issue commonly experienced by people who are new to the language or technology discussed. An ideal beginner-oriented canonical will:

- Meet all the site standards to avoid closure (except as a duplicate - but the other features below will inspire closure the other way around);
- Have an easily searchable title;
- Have a question that is impeccably well written and clear - giving a *truly minimal* MRE for "why" questions and a *simple but exact* specification for "how" questions, all using phrasing that is *technically accurate, but still simple* enough for the target audience to understand;
- Have at least one high-quality answer that is comprehensive and well organized (bonus points for making it community wiki).

Here are some examples from the Python tag:

- [Why does "a == x or y or z" always evaluate to True? How can I compare "a" to all of those?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503)
- [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658)
- [How slicing in Python works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211)
- [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178)
- ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941)
- [Strange result when removing item from a list while iterating over it in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089)

You can use a beginner-oriented canonical to close questions, regardless of the perceived skill of the OP, **that are fundamentally about the same question or issue**. To use it, select to vote to close the question, select "Duplicate" from the list of reasons, then select a beginner-oriented canonical **that is actually specific to the question being asked**.

When you find a question that seems like a good candidate as a beginner-oriented canonical, you may want to add it to your "Saves". The duplicate closure interface offers the full power of the site's search - which isn't very good in general; but this implies that the `in:saves` operator can be used to narrow the search down to questions that you have previously identified as canonicals. This dramatically eases the process.

### Closing questions accurately is an expected basic skill

A beginner-oriented canonical is a very powerful tool for keeping tags clean and shutting down reputation-seeking "fastest gun in the west" answers. Therefore, being able to (vote to) close questions as a duplicate, where appropriate, is considered a basic skill for any site curator. Similarly, voting to close is considered basic work you should do yourself before [asking others for help](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) (not applicable, of course, if you [have a gold badge in the tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589)).

A beginner-oriented canonical isn't always the perfect solution, and shouldn't always be the go-to solution to dealing with bad questions. Questions [should **not**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421505) be closed as a duplicate of a general "how to debug the code" canonical simply because OP has not attempted to debug the code. This is because, in nearly every case the question is **not a duplicate**; OP **did not ask anything related to** how to debug the code, but instead asked *what is wrong with the code*.

So, consider *what is wrong with the code*, and act accordingly:

- If you can *see the problem anyway and it is common*, close as a duplicate of a canonical **about the problem**.
- If you can *see the problem anyway and it is idiosyncratic* - i.e., something that *other* beginners *could not be reasonably expected to* do, but something that was clearly caused by OP *not clearly thinking* about the problem or *not carefully typing* - then vote to close as **"not reproducible or caused by a typo".**
- If you can *see the problem anyway and it is "easy" to solve*, **that is not a reason to close** the question. Check for other reasons; if nothing else applies, *leave it open*.
- If you *can't* see a problem directly, but you can *tell that this is because the OP hasn't attempted debugging*, then the question - obviously - **"needs debugging details"**, and should be closed with that reason - *not as a duplicate*.
- If the question appears to be taken from or motivated by homework, a contest, a job interview, a tutorial website etc., **read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822)** and act accordingly. **Many but certainly not all** of these questions should be closed as **"needs more focus"**, because either there is a series of steps that OP needs to follow in order to solve the problem and the question needs to be about just one of them, or OP is showing way too much code for the question actually being asked.
- If the question appears to be *founded on a misconception*, check whether that misconception is a) common and b) *expressible* in a clear manner while making correct and accurate use of terminology. If it isn't, then the question might be "not reproducible or caused by a typo", but in most cases it should be closed as **"needs details or clarity"**. If it *is*, however, **then a beginner-oriented canonical should be identified or created** to cover that misconception.

### When a beginner-oriented canonical can help you

By considering the question you can discover whether it asks about or directly relates to a common problem that beginners ask about - including things like:

- [basic **logic errors**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003) that **follow a specific common pattern** (For this one, I included a specific language-agnostic example because I feel it's really necessary to understand the category)
- how-to questions about **common tasks** (e.g. opening a file; parsing common data formats; making an HTTP connection to somewhere; splitting a string at word boundaries)
- **fundamental techniques** (e.g. how to call a function, pass parameters to arguments, and use a return value; how to collect the results of iteration into some sort of data structure; how to split code across multiple files and have it work)
- **fundamental conceptual issues** about how the language works (e.g. whether it supports pass-by-value and/or pass-by-reference function calling; whether variables have value semantics and/or reference semantics; whether the language has separate concepts of initialization/declaration vs. assignment; whether the language supports an indexed for-loop and/or a foreach loop that iterates over a sequence; whether libraries generally prefer to offer fluent interfaces or enforce command-query separation)
- **common gotchas** ("undefined behaviour" in C and C++; issues with using mutable default arguments in Python; syntax errors *caused by not understanding* the rules for required braces or indentation)

This is almost certainly not an exhaustive list - the specifics of topics for canonicals will depend on the topics and, to a lesser degree, the userbase - but that fact should not be abused.

Properly closing questions can be very difficult. You might have to write your own canonical and answer it yourself, because nobody who *actually has* the question can *properly express* it. If there are already hundreds or even thousands of questions about a single, specific issue, it can become hard to find the best one (and there is no guarantee that any of them are adequate). The **curators of a tag might therefore have to collaborate** to identify the situation (perhaps using the site chat, [for example like the room I created for Python canonicals](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247434)), put together something authoritative, and close old questions [by redirecting them to the new one, which is perfectly in accordance with policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251938).