# Why was this question closed as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions, reopen-closed

My question asks about how to comment a line within a multi-line code segment:

[How to comment out one line of a multiline statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45786420/how-to-comment-out-one-line-of-a-multiline-statement)

It was closed for another question that asks about how to do a line continuation:

[How can I do a line break (line continuation) in Python (split up a long line of source code)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162/how-can-i-do-a-line-break-line-continuation-in-python-split-up-a-long-line-of).

They're not the same question.

Comment: The answers in the proposed dupe tend to be the same as the ones in the closed, questions, right? ("use parentheses, not backslashes"). And the closed question certainly wouldn't benefit from additional answers (the 3 existing ones already say the same thing), and the dupe-closure points users to the more general case. All in all, seems fine to me.

Comment: The *problem* of your question is line continuation. The *answer* of your question is line continuation. How does the line continuation Q&A not cover yours? What do you personally assume to be the criteria for being "the same question" w.r.t. duplicate closure?

Comment: I just now added [Why do indented explicit line continuations not allow comments in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981757/) as a supplementary duplicate link - just to highlight that the comment also can't be a physical line by itself on the next physical line after the continuation character.

Answer (score 8):

I closed this question, as part of a general cleanup of questions about `IndentationError`s. Yours was of course not a garden-variety question that duplicates the [main canonical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722) (which is now at over a thousand linked questions, BTW, making it one of the most "frequent" in the Python tag - [the system works!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426205/)) - but it *is* a duplicate. During this process I found many other questions on a similar theme, with the same fundamental underlying problem.

The problem you encountered is that comments can't be put after the line continuation character (because the syntax doesn't allow it), and the line continuation character can't be put after the comment (because it will be commented out, failing to continue the comment line).

Indeed, this result is [predicted](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining) by the documentation:

> A line ending in a backslash cannot carry a comment. A backslash does not continue a comment. A backslash does not continue a token except for string literals (i.e., tokens other than string literals cannot be split across physical lines using a backslash). A backslash is illegal elsewhere on a line outside a string literal.

There is no overlooked alternative here (there are only two possible ways to rearrange a sequence of two things), so we conclude that a fundamentally different approach is needed.

It seems clear that you already tried both these approaches, found the problem with them - and didn't really need an explanation of *why* they don't work.

Instead, the question is clearly phrased as being about *how* to put comments inside the line. The *goal* of using the line continuation character is to wrap the logical line of code across multiple physical lines. Therefore, fundamentally the *question* is how to do this, in a way that admits comments.

There are fundamentally two ways to wrap the logical line of code across multiple physical lines. The linked canonical explains both. One of them - the one you tried - does not admit comments. The other one does. Therefore, it solves the problem, and answers mentioning it answer the question.

Further, there is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53182/523612) on the canonical which explicitly cites the documentation I mentioned above - admittedly from very old documentation (for Python 2.5, which is in a legacy documentation format and no longer directly available with the docs.python.org version switcher), but the text is identical.

By Stack Overflow standards, the question is clearly a duplicate.