# Which sites are currently linked to most often in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support, statistics

I’m a contributor to [MDN](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22developer.mozilla.org%22%20created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) and have been trying to get some data on how developers use MDN, and how often — including at Stack Overflow.

One interesting find so far: [MDN’s been linked to more than 80 times a day on average in SO Q&As over the last 5 years](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22developer.mozilla.org%22%20created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) (in total, more than 150,000 times over the last 5 years).

That is, roughly every 20 minutes, some SO user posts an MDN link in a question or answer.

In trying to get some perspective on that, I wondered what other comparable docs sites — or really, what sites in general — are getting linked to by SO users relatively frequently in SO.

Thus the question: Which sites are currently linked to most often in Stack Overflow?

Comment: This really isn't a fair comparison unless you limit by tags...

Comment: SO is often used as a search engine. Someone asks a question which could be answered by looking up documentation but the search abilities aren't high enough. Someone else has the search abilities and posts the corresponding link to documentation and duplicates relevant parts of the official documentation. In the ideal cases there should be more, but there are far too many questions here for only being ideal cases.

Answer (score 33):

See also the related [“Which sites are currently linked to most often in Stack Overflow?” data.stackexchange.com query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1577350/which-sites-are-currently-linked-to-most-often-in-stack-overflow) (forked from a query linked to in [a related Meta Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312994/441757)).

The table below shows sites with 30,000 or more links over the last 5 years in SO Q&As.

| Rank | Search used | Links over last 5 years |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | `i.stack.imgur.com` | [`1,661,487`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22i.stack.imgur.com%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |
| 1 | `stackoverflow.com` | [`865,206`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22stackoverflow.com%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |
| 2 | `github.com` | [`829,896`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22github.com%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |
| 3 | `docs.microsoft.com` | [`233,771`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22docs.microsoft.com%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |
| 4 | `developer.mozilla.org` | [`150,296`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22developer.mozilla.org%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |
| 5 | `jsfiddle.net` | [`115,757`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22jsfiddle.net%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |
| 6 | `github.io` | [`102,454`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22github.io%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |
| 7 | `wikipedia.org` | [`97,975`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22wikipedia.org%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |
| 9 | `docs.python.org` | [`84,646`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22docs.python.org%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |
| 10 | `apache.org` | [`66,300`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22apache.org%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |
| 11 | `docs.oracle.com` | [`65,110`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22docs.oracle.com%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |
| 12 | `developer.android.com` | [`63,331`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22developer.android.com%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |
| 13 | `developers.google.com` | [`63,226`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22developers.google.com%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |
| 14 | `codepen.io` | [`54,638`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22codepen.io%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |
| 15 | `npmjs.com` | [`51,068`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22npmjs.com%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |
| 16 | `pandas.pydata.org` | [`50,834`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22pandas.pydata.org%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |
| 17 | `docs.aws.amazon.com` | [`49,228`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22docs.aws.amazon.com%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |
| 18 | `codesandbox.io` | [`47,372`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22codesandbox.io%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |
| 19 | `msdn.microsoft.com` | [`45,802`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22msdn.microsoft.com%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |
| 20 | `cloud.google.com` | [`45,615`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22cloud.google.com%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |
| 21 | `stackblitz.com` | [`44,778`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22stackblitz.com%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |
| 22 | `medium.com` | [`43,978`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22medium.com%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |
| 23 | `php.net` | [`42,288`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22php.net%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |
| 24 | `regex101.com` | [`40,703`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22regex101.com%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |
| 25 | `developer.apple.com` | [`40,066`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22developer.apple.com%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |
| 26 | `w3schools.com` | [`35,447`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22w3schools.com%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |
| 27 | `youtube.com` | [`34,761`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22w3schools.com%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |
| 28 | `cppreference.com` | [`34,382`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22cppreference.com%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |
| 29 | `firebase.google.com` | [`33,598`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22firebase.google.com%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |
| 30 | `djangoproject.com` | [`31,766`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22djangoproject.com%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |
| 31 | `spring.io` | [`30,320`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22spring.io%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |
| 32 | `gist.github.com` | [`30,127`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22gist.github.com%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |

Any other sites which should be added?

---

A few sites that didn’t make the (admittedly arbitrary) 30,000+ links cutoff:

| Search used | Links over last 5 years |
| --- | --- |
| `dbfiddle.uk` | [`28,126`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22dbfiddle.uk%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |
| `angular.io` | [`28,063`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22angular.io%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |
| `laravel.com` | [`27,644`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22laravel.com%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |
| `typescriptlang.org` | [`22,361`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22typescriptlang.org%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |
| `reactjs.org` | [`22,287`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22reactjs.org%22+created%3A2017-04-4%2E%2E) |

Comment: `docs.microsoft.com` is a relatively new invention for MSDN. The domain name changed at least twice. Only recently did they discover *redirection* in order to not completely break all those links. An older one is `msdn.microsoft.com`, but there are more. There was also `technet.microsoft.com` (merged with MSDN into `docs.microsoft.com`?).

Comment: Thanks — I’ve gone ahead and now added results for a `msdn.microsoft.com` search at least. The retirement of older docs sites and moves to new sites is part of the reason I limited it to just the last 5 years — because also, in the case of, for example, Java, the docs were previously at java.sun.com URLs. Maybe it would be better to limit it to just the last 1 year rather than the last 5 years…

Comment: Not all questions, answers and links are equal. Depending on what you want to know from the data, I would either weigh by score or visits or filter by tags.

Comment: I wonder about libraries/frameworks; for instance, I found myself referring to `api.jquery.com` frequently in the past, but with less frequency recently. Same with `momentjs.com`. But perhaps there would be a reverse trend in, say, `angular.io` or `reactjs.org`? It would also be interesting to see how much self-reference there is: `stackoverflow.com` :).

Comment: Interesting. For `mathworks.com`, MATLAB's official docs, it's 32k in total, 9k since 4th April 2017.

Comment: I'm surprised https://idownvotedbecau.se/ didn't make the list

Comment: `google.com` 45,992 results, `codepen.io` 60,638 results, `jsfiddle.net` 441,191 results

Comment: @maraaaaaaaa Thanks, added codepen.io and jsfiddle.net. I didn’t add google.com yet, because I didn’t know how to do a negation to exclude developers.google.com. What search query did you use to get those 45,992 results for google.com?

Comment: @sideshowbarker all I did was `google.com`, actually, I didn't even realize you already have `developers.google.com` on there. And I was just using the SO search bar, don't know if your using a different method or not

Comment: @Sayse i dont think anyone is putting idownvotedbecua.se into a question or answer on the main site, it tends to be in a comment.

Comment: @Nifim - Ah thanks I missed the "question or answer" part of the question

Comment: @Nifim O/T, but idownvotedbecau.se also seems be used less frequently now. Good riddance to its use at all.

Comment: "Only" `12,479 results` for `example.com`, ah-ah...!

Comment: I don't understand how `github.com` can be so high, but thanks for this works

Comment: @Elikill58 very popular tags such as javascript and python are going to be causing a lot of links to it due to github being a haven for open source projects.